# c# Linq sort List by member of nested List

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I've got

```
List<ObjectA> 
ObjectA is a List<ObjectB> 
ObjectB is List<ObjectC>
```

One of ObjectC is class with field ID (I could specify it) and field "Name"

```
var result = List<ObjectA>
.OrderBy(t => t.ObjectB[1]    
.ObjectC   
.Where(c => c.ID.Equals("ID"))  
.FirstOrDefault().Name)
```

- it works.

I want to NOT use strong index for ObjectB. Something like

```
var result = List<ObjectA>
.OrderBy(t => t.ObjectB.Where(s=>s
.ObjectC
.Where(c => c.ID.Equals("ID"))
.FirstOrDefault().Name)
```

- of course it not works :).

So, how could I sort List by Name?

Thanks.

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. The [mcve] will include the sample input data, and be crystal clear what exact output is expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you can leverage using [`SelectMany`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=net-5.0) to flatten the nested collections. Should look something like this:

```
var result = List<ObjectA>
    .OrderBy(t => t.ObjectB
        .SelectMany(s => s.ObjectC)
        .Where(c => c.ID.Equals("ID"))
        .FirstOrDefault()?.Name)
```

Comment: @user3683552 was glad to help!